# Accessing variable inside class from outside function in python

Tags: python, class, methods, python-class

I need to clear the list in certain conditions and the variable containing the list is inside the class function. I need to access the list from outside the class function.

```
Class A:
   def insideclass(self):
       values=[]
       for i in range(10):
           values.append(func())

def func():
    if datetime.time.now()=="2021-06-25 10:15:52.889564":
       values.clear()
return datetime.time.now()


classvariable=A()
classvariable.insideclass()
```

I don't want to use a global variable because I have different methods inside the class with the same variable name.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of `func` and `somecondition`? Could you not add the condition and the call to `clear` to the class method?

Comment: i have edited to show that the condition occurs once in a while

Comment: i want to clear the list outside the class within a function only..

Comment: Pass `values` as an argument to the function and perform the `append` and `clear` in the function?

Comment: Could you please share

Comment: what if the func() has already some arguements? can we pass it too

Comment: Added an example. In `func` do you really want to still append something if the condition is met or can `func` just throw an error and skip that entry?

Comment: I want to clear the list if the contion met.. There will be some values in the list at that time..

Comment: Raising an exception in `func` seems like it would be cleaner? You wouldn't then have to call `clear` in `func` and could call it in the class method

Comment: That is more useful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `values` by passing the list as an argument:

```
class A:
   def insideclass(self):
       values=[]
       for i in range(10):
           func(values)

def func(values):
    now = datetime.time.now()
    if now == "2021-06-25 10:15:52.889564":
        # You can't compare a datetime to a string...
        values.clear()
    values.append(now)
```

You could throw an exception if the condition is met and perform the clear in the class method

```
class A:
   def insideclass(self):
       values=[]
       for i in range(10):
           try:
               values.append(func())
           except:
               values.clear()

def func():
    now = datetime.time.now()
    if now == "2021-06-25 10:15:52.889564":
        raise Exception('This should be a more specific error')
    else:
        return now
```